# Accessing engine routes from Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to access engine routes by using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`.

I have a factory object that creates a string including a dynamically generated url. Currently, I can generate urls by using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.(INSERT PATH NAME)`.

However, it can only access the routes in the main app. I cannot access the routes of engines mounted on the main app.

**Things I have tried**

1. I've tried to use `Rails.application.routes.engine_name` where `engine_name` is the name under which the engine is mounted on the main app.
2. I've tried to use `MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers` to access the routes in the Engine. It works, but I would like to use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` because there are many factory objects like this one, and they are all inheriting from the superclass that delgates `url_helper` to `Rails.application.routes`.

Any suggestions? Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your engine namespace is `EngineName`, it should be:

```rb
EngineName::Engine.routes.url_helpers.some_engine_path
```

Comment: This worked! To clarify, in the above example, only `EngineName` gets replaced with your engine name. `Engine` should remain the literal word `Engine`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use engine route proxy method.
From your example call the url helper using the following syntax as example:

```
my_engine_engine.articles_path
```

To rename the proxy method helper, just edit the routes config file inside your rails application:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine => '/app', :as => 'my_engine'
```

so you can now call the previous example:

```
my_engine.articles_path
```

Comment: This is remotely relevant to my question, and I specified that I have already tried something of this vein.